# How to store timestamp in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

How to store timestamp (`2019-03-05T10:59:09.2996542+00:00`) in MySQL so I use use it in the `ORDER BY` clause?

Comment: modern MySQL versions 5.6+ supports `DATETIME(6)` but the format needs to be `2019-03-05 10:59:09.299654`  so you will mis a very very small precision.

Comment: i need to store  2019-03-05T10:59:09.2996542+00:00 to mysql database which datatype i should use

Comment: You will need to use `VARCHAR` or `CHAR` but be warned your will be stuck using functions like `DATE_FORMAT()` or `STR_TO_DATE()` to parse out dates, times and other stuff in the future and to get the correct order when using `ORDER BY`, so i advice you to follow mine first comment because you don't have the trouble there.

Comment: i am reading the data from csv file and store it using  LOAD DATA INFILE query

Comment: With "how to store..." you mean "which data type should I use to store..."?

Comment: i've given some (possible) hints, without a better user case and how you are going to use the data iám unable to help futher.

Comment: yes sir , which data type should I use to store